# log4net is not writing to two RollingFileAppenders

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

This is my app config

```
   <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type='log4net.Util.PatternString' value='%property{LogPath}\%property{LogFileName}' />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>   
    <appender name="PerformanceLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type='log4net.Util.PatternString' value='%property{LogPath}\%property{PerformanceLogFileName}' />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="1" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger Name="PerformanceLogger" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="PerformanceLogger"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

When I try to get loggers and write to it. It just creates File for PerformanceLogger but does not write to it.

```
log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
performaceLog = LogManager.GetLogger("PerformanceLogger");
```

but my `log.Info("test");` works fine and it creates a file and also writes to it.

Any Advice on this, please?

Comment: As it seems from your XML configuration you don't have `<logger>` tag for `RollingFileAppender` and also inside your `<root>`. although  I added the missing xml it didn't for me either. I remember long ago when I decided to use a logging lib i tested log4net and it was a headache at the time and I used [Nlog](https://nlog-project.org/download/) and it worked like a charm

Comment: @MohamadArmoon: even if I add logger for my RollingFileAppender , it does not make any difference. I will wait if could not found the reason then I will go for Nlog

Comment: Assuming that the configuration in your question is exactly what you're using in your application, then you have incorrectly used `Name` (upper-case "N") instead of `name` in the `logger` element defining "PerformanceLogger".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger definition for the PerformanceLogger is incorrect - you have used `Name` instead of `name` to define the logger's name. Change this to the following and it should work correctly:

```
...
<logger name="PerformanceLogger" additivity="false">
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="PerformanceLogger"/>
</logger>
...
```